# how can I extract data of list pages from wikipedia?

Tags: scala, rdf, wikipedia, semantic-web, dbpedia

what exactly I want to do is:

**input**: wikipedia xml dump

**output**: a list of triples like this:

```
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Lists_of_computer_languages> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiListOf> <http://dbpedia.org/resource/C_(programming_language)> .

<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Lists_of_computer_languages> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiListOf> <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Java_(programming_language)> .

...

..

.

<http://dbpedia.org/resource/List_of_XML_markup_languages> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiListOf> <http://dbpedia.org/resource/AdsML> .

<http://dbpedia.org/resource/List_of_XML_markup_languages> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiListOf> <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Agricultural_Ontology_Service> .
```

We have already set up and customised dbpedia extraction framework but I think it would be difficult to configure the framework for extracting this data. I was shocked by the fact that extraction framework does not have any extractors for this !

Comment: If I read that correctly, am I right in understanding that you're criticizing *your own* "extraction framework" and then asking how to use it better? Without any knowledge of this framework or where you're sourcing the data, this question is impossible to answer!

Comment: no we did not cusomize dbpedia extraction framework we just add a simple extractor to it

Comment: Also asked at http://www.semanticoverflow.com/questions/2926/how-can-i-extract-data-of-list-pages-from-wikipedia

Comment: @Kevin The extraction framework is part of the open source project DBPedia project and detailed at http://wiki.dbpedia.org/Documentation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the framework extractors look for specific patters in an article name, or in an article body. If you can identify something in the list pages that do not exist in any other article then it will be able to create one...

otherwise you can use the pagelinks (links from page to page) and filter the articles you want. This will probably give you what you want (sort of)

Comment: I used this way and it solved my problem relatively (extractor must find all pages with names started by list_of and extract all links of these pages except category links) but I think there is still better way for solve this problem because still some unrelated links was extracted by this method

Comment: I used the framework and wrote a couple of extractors myself, but the list pages is "problematic"... You cannot identify them (List_Of is not something standard in wikipedia) and (most important) you cannot differentiate the links inside them. That's why i told you to use directly the pagelinks